# Which technique for locating many similar Base Pointer Adresses (fast)?

Tags: windows, pointers, assembly, memory, ollydbg

I try to catch some **Base Pointer Adresses** from a Windows Application which I want to Bot (Its not a game, Its an Online Broker). So, I know how to find Base Pointer Adresses, but I do this with Cheatengine (Find Adresses, set Breakpointes, search for the Output Adresses... and so on) - but this takes very much time for Base Pointers with 6+ Offsets. Maybe there is a much faster technique how to scrape them out of Memory?

**And here is my presumption:** In  [This Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyDBm.png)  you can see, there are many similar Entrys (Forex Entrys), and they are all similar structured. They have a Adress for Ask-Value and Bid-Value - these are the Pointers I need! The Values are represented as Double. Maybe, I can find multiple Adresses at once, if I find the one from another. I thought on object oriented programing, where many Instances have Adresses nearby to the other. So, is there a way to find multiple at once, and fast?

I tried some stuff with OllyDbg, and didnt find some nearby (But my skills with OllyDbg are not insane, I still dont know all functions of it). Do you guys have a better solution, how I can find them faster? I dont really want to code some stuff in Assembler - but if nececary, I can do this. Would be great if you can help. There are 89 Entrys, and I will need per something like 20 - 30 minutes. Would be awful.

Cheers!

- Filthy Frank

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest to read the page [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Probably you want to edit your question afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: Hey man! What's so bad on this question? Still too confusion title? Or the amount of text? I rode the page you linked, but cant find the mistake ^^ But ty, I will try it.

Comment: Make sure what you are trying to do is legal. Also consider simply using the underlying communication if that's feasible.

Comment: I suggest to add some concrete efforts in form of code. Else the question is so broad that concrete help is hardly possible.

Comment: Alright. So, what I am try to do is 100% legal, and there isn't some Code which I could post. Like I said, I want to locate the Base Pointer Adress, dont write a program which do that for me ^^ I just want some help with the technique how to figure that out. I edited my post a bit, hope its okay now.

Comment: I'm confused by the term "Base pointer address". Do you want to extract those numbers from the application? If yes, have you analysed it with a tool like [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2015)? Maybe the app use a label or something.

Comment: what is base pointer ? ebp ? or rather clarify how do you find whatever you are finding wiht ce

Answer (score 0):

Using pointers and offsets is not the correct way to go about this.  On the back end they're just using HTTP and an API.  You should either use that directly or hook the function that does it and then work with the data right after it is received by the client.